# Adding ASP MVC authentication after initial creation of project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have already created a lot of the ground work ( views , viewmodels, controllers, models ) but i would like to now add the authentication. I did not however add this in the initial creation process and was just wondering if there was a way to add the standard authentication that would normally be created if one did select the authentication type.

Is it possible to load this authentication based on the project already created without the laborious task of having to change every namespace and using, and have the required references pulled down.

Thanks

Comment: Additional to what @ScottSelby already mentioned ... just create an application with the appropriate template and integrate the authentication code to your existing project.

Comment: @ScottSelby yes yes .. google. I did google it and could not find an answer. I should maybe go to page 2. Or maybe rephrase my text.

Comment: @ScottSelby .. bro there is nothing on google or bing for that matter. Horizon_Net The problem with your suggestion is the amount of  namespace configuration that i want to avoid. It would be ideal if there was a clean way to do this.